# Update gridview instantly from/inside loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to update GridView data dynamically at runtime.

My requirement is to update the gridview instantly not after finishing the loop. Is this possible?

I want to show progress status in GridView row, e.g. Working..., Pending... and Completed...

I know how to update gridview dynamically but the progress showing after the loop completes execution.

Below is the kind of code I want to run -

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCSVData.Rows)
{
    // Update the row state as Working.
    // I want to show user this status, not after iterating 
    // all the rows of GridView but just after the setting the status.
    row.Cells[4].Text = "Working...";                                    

    // Work with the row here, do something..

    // Update the row state as completed.
    // I want to show user this status, not after iterating 
    // all the rows of GridView but just after the setting the status.
    row.Cells[4].Text = "Completed";
}
```

Scenario -

If the GridView has 10 rows then I want to show status in one of the cell in each row I am working with in GridView. e.g. "Working" if I am working with the row and "Completed" after I am done with the row. And then move to next row in GridView. I want user to show status of the work.

Comment: Would you please share some code?

Comment: Please post your code. How does your model look like? Does the loop run on the server side? If so, you can't "pause" the execution to return stuff to the client, at least not in a way that would make sense.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, Yes its a server side code. Is there any way to show user the status of work ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Not that I know of. What you could do though, is you can run the loop using JavaScript on the client side. In the body of the loop, change the status to "Working", make an ajax call to the server to process the data, and on `success` callback, change the status to "completed".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I'll do the very same thing.